# Turn case sensitivity off in regular expression replacement

Tags: regular-expressions

Converting a subversion repo to git, and setting up an authors file. I'm running `query-replace-regexp` on this text:

```
E001234
```

using this regexp:

```
^\(.*\)$ -> \1 = Some Lowercase Text Here <email@example.com>
```

When I execute the replacement, the replacement text is being capitalized like this, due to the case sensitive nature of replacements:

```
E001234 = SOME LOWERCASE TEXT HERE <EMAIL@EXAMPLE.COM>
```

I understand what's happening, but is there a way to turn this off w/o writing a custom function (trivial, but still...)?

Comment: Tried this:`Query replace regexp (default ^\(.*\)$ -> \1 = \,(substring "OneAmerica Former Employee <email.address@example.com>" 0)): ` but no dice. Seems the replacing operates on the text after it's created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the variable `case-replace` to `nil` before executing the command.  Then you will get the following replacement

```
E001234 = Some Lowercase Text Here <email@example.com>
```

as expected.  When `case-replace` is non-`nil` it preserves case in replacements, i.e. the case of the replacement matches that of the matched text.

Note, there is also the variable `case-fold-search` which also affects case in the match and as well as the replacement.

Comment: So sounds like I'd have to set that variable, run all my query-replace-regexp commands, then unset it? No way to toggle it as part of running query-replace-regexp?

Comment: Indeed.  There is no why standard way to invoke `query-replace-regexp` with a particular choice of case matching option.  Instead it is controlled via these variables.

Comment: @scottplumlee You can write a wrapper function that sets that variable in a `let` and then calls the `query-replace-regexp`. Let me know if you want me to elaborate that.

Comment: @kaushalmodi That's the method I am going to try, thanks.